# Between not included the end date in oracle

Tags: oracle

I am writing the query like 
`select * from tablename where date  between '27-mar-2015' and '1-apr-2015'`.

but records with date `'1-apr-2015'` is not retrieved from the oracle database date type is `TIMESTAMP(6)`.

Comment: Your string literal `1-apr-2015'` is implicitly converted to a timestamp with the time set to `00:00:00` so any rows with a time after midnight on 2015-04-01 will not be included.

Comment: is there any solution for this?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name are you sure? I would bet that implicit conversion works other way around. date is converted to string and string comparsion takes place.

Comment: @ibre5041: if you try `where date_column between 'foo' and 'bar'` you will see that Oracle tries to convert `'foo'` to a date, not `date_column` to a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> between '27-mar-2015' and '1-apr-2015'

'27-mar-2015' is NOT a DATE, it is a string literal. You are forcing Oracle to do an implicit datatype conversion.

> date type is TIMESTAMP(6)

Since your data type is **TIMESTAMP**, you need to take care of the precision of the TIMESTAMP datatype which holds fractions of a second to a precision between 0 and 9 decimal places, the default being 6.

```
BETWEEN 
   to_timestamp('27-mar-2015 01.01.01.000001','dd-mon-yyyy HH24:MI:SS.FF') 
AND
   to_timestamp('01-apr-2015 23.59.59.999999','dd-mon-yyyy HH24:MI:SS.FF')
```

For example,

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET nls_timestamp_tz_format = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT
  2    to_timestamp('27-mar-2015 01.01.01.000001','dd-mon-yyyy HH24:MI:SS.FF') st,
  3    to_timestamp('01-apr-2015 23.59.59.999999','dd-mon-yyyy HH24:MI:SS.FF') end
  4  FROM dual
  5  /

ST                                    END
----------------------------------    ----------------------------------
27-MAR-15 01.01.01.000001000 AM       01-APR-15 11.59.59.999999000 PM

SQL>
```

Comment: shall i start with "27-mar-2015 00.00.00.000000000"

Comment: You could, but that will make it `27-MAR-15 12.00.00.000000000 AM`

Comment: Exactly! Midnight of the previous day. That is the start of current day.

Answer (score 1):

You have to note that `timestamp`-columns (and with oracle even `date`-columns) always include the time of day and that `date '1-apr-2015'` actually means `'1-apr-2015 00:00:00'` - then everything makes sense. The exact string-representation of timestamps might vary according to the configured locale.

To get date including the first of april you best use `between ... and '2-apr-2015'` if you don't mind having the first microsecond of that day included.

Comment: The columns are `timestamp` not `date` - but your answer is still correct

Comment: I have tried what ever you said and got the following error. "hour must be between 1 and 12"

Comment: `you best use between ... and '2-apr-2015'` Are you suggesting the solution to let implicit data type conversion happen? OP might just be lucky to see the implicit conversion happening if the format matches the locale-specific NLS format, else it will error out.

Comment: It would certainly be preferable to use `to_date` with a specified format - but I didn't want to mix up too many problems in one answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try convert to_date:

```
select * from tablename 
where date  between to_Date('27-mar-2015','dd-mm-yyy') 
and to_date('1-apr-2015','dd-mm-yyyy')
```

Comment: Won't include `2015-04-01 00:00:01`

Comment: tried and got the following error "SQL Error: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"

Comment: `to_Date('27-mar-2015','dd-mm-yyy') ` The format is different for the month. Use, `mon` and not `mm`. By the way, OP's data type is timestamp and not date.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue. Using TRUNC Date Function helped.

select * from tablename where trunc(date,'DAY')  between '27-mar-2015' and '1-apr-2015'

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this code:

```
select * from tablename where to_date(date,'DD-MON-YYYY')  between '27-mar-2015' and '1-apr-2015'.
```

Comment: it is giving following error "date format picture ends before converting entire input string"

Comment: I did not downvote your solution, but thought to explain. `to_date(date,'DD-MON-YYYY')` will convert the date into string with local NLS format and then convert back to DATE. Which is wrong and should be avoided. You need `TO_DATE` to convert string into date.